# Ubuntu 12.10 - xinput test 8 command which shows where i am touching the screen, but its showing me nothing at all

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, kernel, xorg, touchpad

I have `xinput test 8` to see touch screen inputs. But since 5 hours i can not see where its touching. Before 5 hours it was working fine.

Then i updated the kernel and also updated to latest kernel but the problem remain same as always. How can i make sure the `xinput test 8` capture of touchscreen is working at all or not?

```
$ download http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/
wget http://91.189.94.216/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/linux-image-3.5.1-030501-generic_3.5.1-030501.201208091310_amd64.deb
wget http://91.189.94.216/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/linux-image-extra-3.5.1-030501-generic_3.5.1-030501.201208091310_amd64.deb
wget http://91.189.94.216/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/linux-headers-3.5.1-030501-generic_3.5.1-030501.201208091310_amd64.deb
wget http://91.189.94.216/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/linux-headers-3.5.1-030501_3.5.1-030501.201208091310_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
$ init 6


$ udevadm info --export-db | grep Elo
E: ID_MODEL=Elo_TouchSystems_2700_IntelliTouch_r__USB_Touchmonitor_Interfac
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Elo\x20TouchSystems\x202700\x20IntelliTouch\x28r\x29\x20USB\x20Touchmonitor\x20Interface
E: ID_SERIAL=Elo_TouchSystems__Inc._Elo_TouchSystems_2700_IntelliTouch_r__USB_Touchmonitor_Interfac_20E10439
E: ID_VENDOR=Elo_TouchSystems__Inc.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Elo\x20TouchSystems\x2c\x20Inc.


$ sudo evtest /dev/input/event3
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x4e7 product 0x20 version 0x100
Input device name: "Elo TouchSystems, Inc. Elo TouchSystems 2700 IntelliTouch(r) USB Touchmonitor Interface"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
    Event code 40 (ABS_MISC)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      256
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working with old kernel, latest all kernels does not work and its slow when touch is pressed.

```
$ sudo modprobe elo`
$ uname -r 
3.2.0-29-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question whether your touch screen completely stopped working, or that it's just `xinput test` that stopped working.

In the latter case: It is possible that the device id `8` has changed. Try running

```
xinput list
```

and see what id number it says next to your touch screen. Then substitute it like

```
xinput test NUMBER
```

Comment: YES - the id is 8 but still not working

Comment: See my above edit, nothing happens when i touch.